# Create Drupal 7 Multi Site on Mac OSX 10.10

Tags: multi-sites, installation

I want to create a Drupal Multisite so I can share my theme and users between two sites. I want to set it up locally before I upload it on a webhost.

I am using Mac 10.10. However, many of the tutorials seem to be written for older versions of Mac OSX and don't work properly.

For example, [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/111710) suggests the following:

Edit /etc/apache2/http.conf to add the following:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot /Users/YOURSITE/Sites/drupal
ServerName drupal1.localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot /Users/YOURSITE/Sites/drupal
ServerName drupal2.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Then edit  /etc/hosts to add the following:

```
127.0.0.1     drupal1.localhost
127.0.0.1     drupal2.localhost
```

You can now find your site at: http://drupal1.localhost & http://drupal2.localhost

When I do this, I just get the message "It Works" I am unable to go to the Druapl installation page to start installing the site.

I've had a search for other tutorials, but they all seem to be written for MAMP.

How can I fix it, without using MAMP?

Comment: Did you restart apache after making changes to http.conf?

Comment: @PatrickRyan. Yes, I did "sudo apachectl restart"

Comment: Did you edit the `DocumentRoot` and the `<Directory "/some/default/path"></directory>` to point to your Drupal installation?  I'm referring to the DocRoot and Directory outside of your Vhost

Comment: @PatrickRyan Which file would I edit that in. Is it located in /etc/. I am quite new to this, so I'm not sure which file path to look in. Thanks!

Comment: It should be in the same file, http.conf

Comment: @PatrickRyan In my  /etc/apache2/http.conf there is only the text I have put in my Opening post. How do I add a Document Root. Also, do I just paste in `<Directory "/some/default/path"></directory>` or do I need to add more text in between the directory tags.

Comment: Your http.conf should have a lot more than just your code in it by default.  At the very least, above all your vhost settings add `DocumentRoot "/Users/YOURSITE/Sites/drupal"` and `<Directory "/Users/YOURSITE/Sites/drupal">AllowOverride All</directory>`

Comment: @PatrickRyan Does YOURSITE contain the name of the Drupal folder that will have the multisite, or is it the Mac Account user name?I've tried both and when I visit the URL I get: 404 Not Found.

Comment: It needs to be the exact path to the folder that all the drupal files are in

Comment: @PatrickRyan Yes, I've done that but now the http://drupal1.localhost & http://drupal2.localhost says "Not Found" instead of "it Works". For the multi-site: If I go to the root Druapl directory, I get the installation page. Do I have to install the main Drupal site, before I can install the child sub sites?

Comment: I wrote an answer covering everything since comments are getting messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have your directories configured properly.

Assuming that you have this file structure:

```
/users/
    /drupal/
        /sites/
            /drupal1.localhost/
                /settings.php
            /drupal2.localhost/
                /settings.php
```

Note that the folders under /sites **must match the http.conf server name**.  (unless alias's are set up).

With the above structure, your http.conf would look like this:

```
DocumentRoot "/users/drupal"

<Directory "/users/drupal">
    AllowOverride All
</directory>

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/users/drupal"
    ServerName drupal1.localhost
    <Directory "/users/drupal">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/users/drupal"
    ServerName drupal2.localhost
    <Directory "/users/drupal">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the document root points to the base Drupal folder, not /sites.  Drupal will handle this part automatically.

Your hosts file would remain the same:

```
127.0.0.1     drupal1.localhost
127.0.0.1     drupal2.localhost
```